# Retrieve a number from a table by EF

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, c#-4.0

Entity Frame 5.0 question.

I am new to Entity Frame, basically I have a table "MyPIN".

```
[Table("MyPIN")]
public class BatchPINDetail
{
    public BatchPINDetail();
    public int Number { get; set; }
```

I want to run a query

```
int x = the biggest Number FROM MyPIN
```

The correspond codes are:

```
public class InContext : DbContext
{
    public InContext();
    public InContext(string connectionString);

    public DbSet<BatchDetail> BatchDetailsRecords { get; set; }

}
```

Question 1: I am not sure how to retrieve it.

Question 2: After I get the value, I want to reassign the value, say Number += 1; I need to write it to DB.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
InContext inContext = new InContext(cnStr);
// get first biggest item
BatchPINDetail entity = inContext.BatchDetailsRecords
                                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.Number)
                                 .First();
// get all biggest items
BatchPINDetail entities = inContext.BatchDetailsRecords
                                 .Where(x => x.Number == x.Max(x => x.Number))
                                 .ToArray();

// and if you just want to get biggest number. 
// but note that if you just change `num` nothing will happen.
int num = inContext.BatchDetailsRecords.Max(x => x.Number);

entity.Number += 1;
inContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: There may be have duplicate, say the bigger number is 50. There are several 50. Is that okay?

Comment: I want to get this number, say int x = inContext.BatchDetailsRecords
                                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.Number)
                                 .First();

Answer (score 0):

You can use direct approach like the following code and avoid forth and back call to the database.

```
    InContext inContext = new InContext(cnStr);
    string Sql="SELECT *  FROM MyPIN where Number in (Select MAX(Number) from MyPIN)";
    BatchPINDetail[] entities = inContext.BatchDetailsRecords.SqlQuery(Sql).ToArray();
```

Now you can do your changes and call SaveChanges() after that.